# Node recursive promise never exits

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following recursive function that recursively calls an iterator

The conversions.next() call is a request-promise call to the next page of an api endpoint

The conversions.done just checks if there are no more pages

This loop is kicked off by passing a call to the api endpoint as the first parameter.

The problem is that my node process never exits using this, I seem to have 10 + open TCP socket connections when the process._getActiveHandles() is run at the end of the code, but node has no further code to execute, but does not exit

```
const loadConversions = function loadConversions(httpCallPromise, allConversions) {
  allConversions = typeof allConversions !== 'undefined' ? allConversions : [];
  return httpCallPromise.then((conversions) => {
    allConversions = allConversions.concat(conversions.value);
    if (conversions.done === false) {
      return loadConversions(conversions.next(), allConversions);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(allConversions);
  });
};


// this is the entry point for the code
if (args[0] === 'conversions') {
  loadConversions(queries.conversions())
  .then((allConversions) => {
    console.log(allConversions.length);
    return Promise.all(allConversions.map(db.insertConversion));
   })
   .then(() => {
     console.log('done db insertions');
     console.log(process._getActiveHandles().length);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
   });
}
```

the output of process.getActiveHandles().length is 13 node processes of type tcp socket

Here is the iterator

```
const cakeRequest = function(options) {
// make the request
return rp(options)
.then((response) => {
  const processed = processResponse(response);
  return {
  next: function next() {
    const nextOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
      qs: Object.assign({}, options.qs, {
        start_at_row: parseInt(options.qs.start_at_row, 10) + parseInt(options.qs.row_limit, 10),
      }),
    });
    return cakeRequest(nextOptions);
  },
  value: processed.value,
  done: processed.done,
  row_count: processed.row_count,
  };
})
.catch(handleError);
};
```

Comment: Please show us your implementation of that iterator and your initial call of `loadConversions`. It looks like `done` is staying `false` forever.

Comment: I added the iterator implementation and the initial call. What is strange is that the console.log('done db insertions') runs, despite there being no code after it, the process never exits

Comment: There is a good chance its not related to the actual recrusive promise part since it does execute that later code, I dont know what else could keep a node process open though.

Comment: Yes, if "`done db insertions`" is logged then your recursion has succeeded. What is this `db` thing, does it need to be closed explicitly? And does `insertConversion` need a `this` context?

Answer (score 0):

My Issue seemed to be with the knex library used for the DB insert. If the pool is never closed, the process never exits. This seems like strange behavior to me, but calling knex.destroy at the end let the process exit